# GRE argument pool documents design

Tags: two-column, paragraphs

I'm currently preparing the GRE test.

In the AW writing section, I need to review all the argument topic pool, which are different essays -- PHDs should know what I am talking about. So I would like to design a handy PDF file contains all essays on left and leave some blank space on right so that I can print out and make some note on it.

The document in my head should like this:
[image]
Could you give me some hints or suggestions using which package that I can end up like this?

It involves the paragraph design, and column display I guess.

Thanks a lot! I'm new to latex and I can only use templates.

Comment: Use the [`tufte-handout` or `tufte-book`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) documentclass.  It has a very large right margin where you can take notes.

Comment: Welcome, [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) <- A free ebook to get you started.

Comment: There are also complete examples available on how to use `tufte-book` [tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.tex)/[pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf) or `tufte-handout` [tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-handout.tex)/[pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-handout.pdf)